# Neo4j storing multiple values as property and matching nodes based on that property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a label `Person` with nodes that have certain properties (forename, surname etc.) and I have a label `Company` with nodes with certain properties (name, companyNumber etc.). Now I need to add property `compNumber` to the person nodes which will indicate in which companies that person works.
My question is: Is there a way to put multiple values in the property compNumber, for example

```
(:Person {forename:John, surname'Smith', compNumber:[001,002,003]})
```

and later make a relationship `WORKS_AT` if the property `companyNumber` in `Company` node matches one of the values in `compNumber` property?

Or, will a better approach to store `compNumber` values as separate nodes be like:

```
(:Person {forename:John, surname:Smith})-[:HAS_NUMBER]->(:Number {compNumber:001})
(:Person {forename:John, surname:Smith})-[:HAS_NUMBER]->(:Number {compNumber:002})
(:Person {forename:John, surname:Smith})-[:HAS_NUMBER]->(:Number {compNumber:003})
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't create relationships to the companies with the given compNumber, and create new Company nodes as necessary if no Company exists yet with the given CompNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in the way you want it. In Neo4j you can set an array property with following command:

```
CREATE (:Person {forename:'John', surname:'Smith', compNumber:[1,2,3]});
```

You can search for specific nodes with the IN keyword:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE 1 IN n.compNumber RETURN n;
```

Then you can create relations in the following way:

```
MATCH (n:Company) MATCH (p:Person) WHERE n.companyNumber IN p.compNumber MERGE (p)-[:WORKS_IN]->(n);
```

I think this solution should fit you needs.